Why Alpine x-data doesn't react to its own property changes?
There is an input component. Code below.
@props([
'disabled' => false,
'hidden' => false,
'type' => 'text',
'state' => null,
'borderClass' => ''
])

@php
switch ($state){
    case 'alert':
        $borderClass = 'border-2 border-red-600';
        break;
    case 'success':
        $borderClass = 'border-2 border-green-600';
        break;
}

@endphp

<input x-data="{
    borderClass: @js($borderClass),
    removeBorderClass() {

        // for testing
        document.querySelectorAll('[x-data]').forEach(el => {
            console.log(el);
        });
        console.log(document.getElementById('title'));
        // end for testing

        if (@js($borderClass)){
            let classes = this.borderClass.split(' ');
            $refs.input.classList.remove(...classes);
        }
    }
}"
    x-ref="input"
    x-on:focus="removeBorderClass()"

    value = "{{ $slot ?? '' }}"
    type = "{{ $type }}"
    {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }}
    {{ $hidden ? 'hidden' : '' }}
    {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-indigo-600 focus:border shadow-sm sm:text-sm rounded-md border-gray-300 ' . $borderClass]) }}
 >

After changing $state property and the $borderClass property, I get changes on the screen with border color, i.e. border-2 border-red-600 is added to DOM, but I don't get any change for alpine when calling x-on:focus=removeBorderClass()
I have decided to test the result and implement console.log in method by using two different ways to get the same DOM element. 1. by 'x-data' selector and by 'id'
    // for testing
    document.querySelectorAll('[x-data]').forEach(el => {
        console.log(el);
    });
    console.log(document.getElementById('title'));
    // end for testing

Here is the result from browser devtools. For
1.
document.querySelectorAll('[x-data]').forEach(el => {
                console.log(el);
            });

Result (only part for our input element):
<input x-data="{
    borderClass: '',
    removeBorderClass() {

        // for testing
        document.querySelectorAll('[x-data]').forEach(el => {
            console.log(el);
        });
        console.log(document.getElementById('title'));
        // end for testing

        if (''){
            let classes = this.borderClass.split(' ');
            $refs.input.classList.remove(...classes);
        }
    }
}" x-ref="input" x-on:focus="removeBorderClass()" value="" type="text" class="focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-indigo-600 focus:border shadow-sm sm:text-sm rounded-md border-gray-300  w-full" style="margin-right: -2.75rem;" name="depth" wire:model.lazy="depth" placeholder="0" title="depth">




console.log(document.getElementById('title'));

Result:
<input x-data="{
    borderClass: 'border-2 border-red-600',
    removeBorderClass() {

        // for testing
        document.querySelectorAll('[x-data]').forEach(el => {
            console.log(el);
        });
        console.log(document.getElementById('title'));
        // end for testing

        if ('border-2 border-red-600'){
            let classes = this.borderClass.split(' ');
            $refs.input.classList.remove(...classes);
        }
    }
}" x-ref="input" x-on:focus="removeBorderClass()" value="" type="text" class="focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-indigo-600 focus:border shadow-sm sm:text-sm rounded-md border-gray-300 border-2 border-red-600 w-full" wire:model.lazy="title" name="title" id="title">

Why they are different. Why while calling the same element get different results? How get changes with alpine?

I did a test and your code works perfectly for me.
The main advice I can give you is to rebuild the assets if you use some new Tailwind classes, otherwise the classes may not be applied.
Using Vite:

npm run build

or

npm run dev


On the other hand, removing classes via javascript may be unnecessary, it would be sufficient to define the counterpart by default with the prefix focus:
@props([
'disabled' => false,
'hidden' => false,
'type' => 'text',
'state' => null,
'borderClass' => ''
])

@php
    switch ($state){
        case 'alert':
            $borderClass = 'border-2 border-red-600 text-orange-400';
            break;
        case 'success':
            $borderClass = 'border-2 border-green-600 text-fuchsia-600';
            break;
    }

@endphp

<input x-data
       x-ref="input"
       value = "{{ $slot ?? '' }}"
       type = "{{ $type }}"
    {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }}
    {{ $hidden ? 'hidden' : '' }}
    {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'focus:text-slate-950 focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-indigo-600 ' .
                                      'focus:border shadow-sm sm:text-sm rounded-md border-gray-300 ' .
                                      $borderClass]) }}
>

In this example I have added the class focus:text-slate-950 in the default list and set text-orange-400 for the alert state and text-fuchsia-600 for the success state: the browser will apply the appropriate style using the Tailwind classes.

However, if the effect you want to achieve is to permanently remove the classes once the control has gained focus, this may be a solution:
<input x-data="{gotFocus: false}"
       x-ref="input"
       value = "{{ $slot ?? '' }}"
       type = "{{ $type }}"
       @focus="gotFocus=true"
       :class="gotFocus ? '' : '{{ $borderClass }}'"

    {{ $disabled ? 'disabled' : '' }}
    {{ $hidden ? 'hidden' : '' }}
    {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'focus:ring-indigo-600 focus:border-indigo-600 ' .
                                      'focus:border shadow-sm sm:text-sm rounded-md border-gray-300 ']) }}
>

Furthermore, by adding in the example above the event handler @focusout="gotFocus=false" you get the original behavior, which is to manage the class change via javascript
